# How to send /command to discord thru API

Tags: php, discord

I am trying to achieve send command to discord and I need to execute it.For example if I have some for example ticket bot on my channel,as User I can execute command /ticket "my ticket", I wanna to do the same, but execute command like this thru API, ideally CURL.
Have an idea how to achieve this? Thanks a lot
using php/curl, but have no idea how to execute specific slash command at specific channel:
I

```
    $settings = [
        
       
            "name" => "blep",
            "type" => 1,
            "description" => "Send a random adorable animal photo",
                                
           
    ];
    
    $json = json_encode($settings);
   

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1076853235412906165/B1kzN6vwTzd-9idrd8Kyv8p4");       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';       
    


    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    dd($result);
```

Comment: Can we assume you've read https://discord.com/developers/docs/ in detail?

Comment: I did. but if you can hint me if  need to use message component or application command, it would be nice. I tried everything, trying iit for 10+ hours thanks a lot